# Safari doesn't open Native Map application from url iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, ios5, maps

I am having a problem in safari, that it stopped opening native map application in iPhone device from url like **http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=**, it is always opening **google map** inside the browser, in new iOS safari browser, where as the same url works fine in older devices.

Any help would be very appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you find on the internet, you should not use "http://" but should use "maps://". So "http://maps.google.com/?q=paris" will open the Google Maps website but "maps://maps.google.com/?q=paris" will open the native Maps application.